# Is it possible to add observer or notification when statusBarOrientation changed?

Tags: ios, uistatusbar, uideviceorientation

I have a very tricky code, because sometimes I set a new orientation.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Is it possible to add observer or notification when statusBarOrientation changed? I want to know what is the current orientation.

Comment: Interesting que! I would suggest u to TIY first & then post if some issues they occur. It also matters a lot what r u doing upon orientation of device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is very very tricky.

The property you are using is declared as the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIDeviceOrientation orientation
```

So, your app will get rejected when using this private method.

If you want to change the interface orientation then you should look into the `UIViewController` callbacks.

About your question you could do it manually. Send a custom notification after setting the new orientation. Then catch that notification wherever you want. But be aware of what I previously said.

For further info you could see this stackoverflow topic on [method-uidevice-setorientation-is-it-still-denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257464/method-uidevice-setorientation-is-it-still-denied).

Hope it helps.